# Windows utility for consuming CPU

Tags: utilities, stress-testing, cpu-cycles

I'm looking for a windows utility to consume CPU at a specified percentage so that I can test my app under conditions of restricted processor resources.

I googled around and saw a reference to CPUGRAB.exe, but can't find a download location.

Comment: Have you thought of using MS Office or one of the fabulous Rational tools? They're ideal for this sort of thing :-)

Comment: Or (upgrade to vista if not yet using) hibernate Your pc instead of shutting down so that it has 3 days of uptime. That should do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Max CPU](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2005/10/21/428192.aspx) will do some of what you want but doesn't have the percentage granularity.

Answer (score 1):

Google for just cpugrab. There are `cpugrab.zip` and `cpugrab.rar` files all over the place (rapidshare, badongo, etc). They may or may not be legal, I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

[Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/)

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you need CPU Speed Adjuster. It is freeware unlike some others:

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/CPU-Speed-Adjuster.shtml

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows XP laptop, compiling `bogdown.c`:

```
int main(void) {
    int i;
    while ( 1 ) ++i;
    return 0;
}
```

w/o any optimizations and then starting two instances uses utilizes both cores to the max and makes starting any program or typing into the textbox on SO a chore.

If you want to make it harder for the OS to take away time slices from `bogdown.exe`, you can increase the priorities of the processes in Task Manager, but beware, your system may become very unresponsive.

If you want to simulate limited memory, `calloc` (not `malloc`) a gigabyte or two of memory in `bogdown.exe`.

Another alternative is to have at least a couple of programs encoding video while you test your app.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an Open Source (MIT) replacement for CPUGrab.exe in C#. This came about due to my reluctance to rely on (sometimes) shady download sites purporting to have 'cpugrab.zip'. It seems to work pretty well for SimCopter on my Win98 VM. :)

The tool can be found here: [CPUGrab.NET](http://boredwookie.net/index.php/blog/cpugrab-net/)